# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException error

Tags: powermock

I have a static method A inside a class. I am trying to mock the class A using spy method.

These are the lines I have written.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ConfigManagerProcess.class);
given(ConfigManagerProcess.isApplet()).willReturn(true);
replayAll();
```

It throws the below error message:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
>   when() requires an argument which has to be a method call on a mock.
>
> For example: `when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);`
>
> Also, this error might show up because you stub either of:
>   `final/private/equals()/hashCode()` methods. Those methods *cannot* be
>   stubbed/verified.

Is there any way to call a static method with no arguments in a when statement?

Answer (score 0):

mocking a static method with no arguments should not be an issue.

The following example works and getInstance does not take an argument:

```
mockStatic(ClassA.class);
ClassA mockA = mock(ClassA.class);
when(ClassA.getInstance()).thenReturn(mockA);
```

There might be two things that are causing this, without more code to go on I'm going to post both and you'll have to figure out which one works for you.

If `isApplet()` is a static method, make sure you have the following code at the top of your test class:

`@PrepareForTest({ConfigManagerProcess.class})
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`

If `isApplet()` is NOT a static method, you need to make a MOCK OBJECT first.

`ConfigManagerProcess mockConfigManagerProcess = mock(ConfigManagerProcess.class);
when(mockConfigManagerProcess.isApplet()).thenReturn(true);`

Comment: isApplet is a static method. I added the annotations PrepareForTest and RunWith. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @SaranyaSrinivasan I would love to assist you with this issue. But I need you to edit your question and append the following information for me to actually help you. I need you to show me your test class, and the class you are testing. If its a huge class, please try to shorten it to just a SINGLE method you are trying to mock (and any methods that method may call). I also need the class/method that is calling the method you are mocking.